# cross-reference for multiple-language project

Tags: vim, ide, youcompleteme

I am currently maintaining a project which is a large multi-language project including `python`, `perl`, `bash` and `c/c++` languages. My current IDE is vim with `YouCompleteMe` plugin.

The problem of using this is that `ycm` more or less supports only one language for a project. Therefore, sometime when I encountered a `c` command called in a bash file, it took me a while to search what is the source code of such command, which I could not use `goto` functionality based on `ycm`.

I therefore wonder if there is a way to support such "cross-reference intellisense", e.g., I could `goto` a `c` or `python` command in a bash file ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not very *intelligent*, but a tool like [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/), that supports dozens and dozens of languages, can be used to index your whole project and Vim's built-in tag-related commands can be used to jump to the definition of anything in any filetype as long as there is a tag for it.

See `:help tags`.

Comment: Not sure if any IDE (like vscode) could support this, with multiple plugins ?

Comment: Many IDEs do support ctags.

Comment: sorry I meant to ask if other IDE with plugins could support some "intelligent" cross-reference. Also if limited to vim, should we combine `ctags` and `ycm` together or should we stick to `ctags`? How to compare the two ?

Comment: The general trend is unfortunately going in the opposite direction, with very smart language-specific tooling.